# some limiting information about a function from it's first and second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb R  $ such that both $f^{'}$ and $f^{''}$
are strictly positive on $\mathbb R  $. Then  is there a functon such that $ \lim_{x\to \infty}
f(x) \neq \infty$ ?

I can intuitively imagine the types of functions on $\mathbb R  $ such that both $f^{'}$ and $f^{''}$ are strictly positive on $\mathbb R  $ which grows very slowly and converges to some finite number.But i am not able to find an explicit function or a proof.

Comment: Do you mean $f'$ and $f''$?

Comment: @Adam yes thanks

Comment: See the stronger statement at [Prove that limit goes to infinity if a convex function's derivative > 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513717/prove-that-limit-goes-to-infinity-if-a-convex-functions-derivative-0).

Comment: It would be helpful to have more context about your Question.  Why (for example) does this problem interest you?  Have you considered any special cases (or generalizations)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that limit goes to infinity if a convex function's derivative > 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513717/prove-that-limit-goes-to-infinity-if-a-convex-functions-derivative-0)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=e^{-x}$ as a counterexample

Comment: i just edited the question .Thanks for your help.